# 'at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)' trying to build nextjs website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, node-modules

I was trying to build my nextjs website and got this error

```
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)    
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    errno: -4048,
    code: 'EPERM',
    syscall: 'open',  path: 'E:\\ECell Project\\ecell-uptodat\\ecell-main\\.next\\trace'

}
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

please install

```
npm i memfs --force
```